# Xcode moving multiple Node from base1 to base2 but not have them stack one over each other

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to make multiple node go from point A (starting point of the node) to point B on my storyboard. I succeeded doing that:

```
 let action = SKAction.moveBy(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), duration: movementDuration)
 self.run(action)
```

I repeat that for every Node I have.
The problem is: I cannot see how many node I send to point B because they are all stack over each other so it look like only one Node.

Those Nodes represent a unit in an army, going from point A to B

I was wondering if there was a way to not have them stack over each other, so if I send 5 Node I see 5 unit and not only one (Maybe having a non linear (curve) path that is different for each?).

Thank you for your help

Comment: You say you move all nodes to a particular location.  But you don't want them at the same location?  I'm afraid what you are saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe the nodes should be around point B randomly, but not on it exactly.